# Linking to jQuery tabs from a href

Tags: jquery-ui, jquery-tabs

I'm trying to link to jQuery tabs from **a href**, but it doesn't seem to be working. How do you go about doing this. I want a tab to open when a user clicks on a link. This is my code so far: http://jsfiddle.net/AXEEe/.

**HTML**

```
<a href="#Allocated">Allocated</a>
<a href="#Declined">Declined</a>
<a href="#Pending">Pending</a>
<a href="#Failed">Failed</a>

<div style="padding-top: 10px">
  <div id="tabs">
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#Allocated" id="#Allocated">Allocated Requests</a></li>
      <li><a href="#Declined">Declined Requests</a></li>
      <li><a href="#Pending">Pending Requests</a></li>
      <li><a href="#Failed">Failed Requests</a></li>
      </ul>
          <div id="Allocated">
              Content 1
          </div>
          <div id="Declined">
              Content 2
          </div>
          <div id="Pending">
              Content 3
          </div>    
          <div id="Failed">
              Content 4
          </div>
        </div>
</div>
```

​**JS**

```
$(function() {
        $( "#tabs" ).tabs();
});​
```

Comment: @Jasper What are you talking about? The question and fiddle contain what he's tried so far.

Comment: @Barmar: All I see in the question and fiddle are links and tabs. There seems to be no attempt to connect the two, which is exactly what the question is.

Comment: @Jasper He assumed that the `href` in the links would automatically connect them, just like it does in the tabs div. That's what he tried, it didn't work, so he came here for help. This is more than many others provide in their initial questions, be thankful.

Comment: @Barmar: That's a good point, I didn't realize that and it makes it a much better question (though it still could have used mention of that outside the code). And the fact that without that, it would still have been more than most askers give us doesn't mean that it would have been enough or that we should be happy with it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$(function() {
    $("#tabs").tabs();
    $("a[href=#Allocated]").click(function() {
        $("#tabs").tabs("option", "active", 0);
    });
    $("a[href=#Declined]").click(function() {
        $("#tabs").tabs("option", "active", 1);
    });
    $("a[href=#Pending]").click(function() {
        $("#tabs").tabs("option", "active", 2);
    });
    $("a[href=#Failed]").click(function() {
        $("#tabs").tabs("option", "active", 3);
    });
});​
```

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/barmar/AXEEe/2/)

Answer (score 3):

To select your tabs with link, procees like this : http://jsfiddle.net/AXEEe/1/

```
<a id="0" href="#">Allocated</a>
<a id="1" href="#">Declined</a>
<a id="2" href="#">Pending</a>
<a id="3" href="#">Failed</a>

    $('a').click(function(){
       $("#tabs").tabs("option", "active", parseInt(this.id));
    });
```

For this example, I have just add `id` to your `<a>` link with tab link. You can do better acc. to your project. Ask if you are more questions

**EDIT**

Update tab section method to be compliant with JQUery UI 1.9

Comment: The `select` method is deprecated in jQuery UI 1.9, and is no longer in the documentation.